# Problems splitting a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to read some values from a file, but I keep getting errors when trying to split them up;
The text file looks like this:

```
2009-10 0:12:01
2009-12 0:06:24
2010-06 0:29:24
2012-06 0:10:29
```

Here's my code;

```
myFiles = glob.glob('./*.txt')
for fileName in myFiles:
    fileHandle = open(fileName,'r')
    print str(fileName)
    for date, value in str(fileHandle.readline()).split(' ',1):
        print "date: " + str(date)
        print "value: " + str(value)
```

What I want to output:

```
<filename>
date: 2009-10
value: 0:12:01
date: 2009-12
value: 0:06:24
date: 2010-06
value: 0:29:24
date: 2012-06
value: 0:10:29
<filename>
etc
etc...
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scratch.py", line 16, in <module>
    for date, value in str(fileHandle.readlines()).split(' ',1):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Aside: please always make sure you're running the code you post.  Your code says `str(fileHandle.readline()).split(' ',1)`, without an `s`, but your traceback says your *real* code has one: `str(fileHandle.readlines()).split(' ',1)`.

Comment: sorry for that, ive run it a bunch of different ways and still come back to this error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not iterating over the lines in your file correctly:

```
    for date, value in str(fileHandle.readline()).split(' ',1):
```

This iterates over the two fields in the first line only: `['2009-12', '0:06:24\n']`. Each field is a single string, so can't be unpacked into `date, value`. Why not try the more direct:

```
import glob

myFiles = ['input.txt']
for fileName in myFiles:
    fileHandle = open(fileName,'r')
    print str(fileName)
    for line in fileHandle:
        date, value = line.split()
        print "date: " + str(date)
        print "value: " + str(value)

input.txt
date: 2009-10
value: 0:12:01
date: 2009-12
value: 0:06:24
date: 2010-06
value: 0:29:24
date: 2012-06
value: 0:10:29
```

Comment: this gives:  need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @Radamand: I get the output I've added to my code when I run it with `input.txt` containing your example input.

Answer (score 3):

When the line is split once, it gives a list. When you iterate the list, like the way you have done, with `for`, it expects it to be an iterable of items, each of which can be unpacked over two variables.

Your `for` statement is equivalent to this, after reading the first line

```
for date, value in ['2009-10', '0:12:01']:
    ...
```

That is why it fails with that error.

A better way to do this would be,

```
import glob

# Iterate the found files
for fileName in glob.glob('./*.txt'):
    # Open the file with `with` statement
    with open(fileName, "r") as fileHandle:
        print str(fileName)

        # Give date and value from each line, with generator expression
        for date, value in (line.strip().split(' ',1) for line in fileHandle):
            # Print with the template string
            print "date: {}\nvalue: {}".format(date, value)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach to the problem

```
with open ("path to file\\test.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:  
        date, value = line.split()
        print "date: {}".format(date)
        print "value: {}".format(value)
```

output:

```
date: 2009-10
value: 0:12:01
date: 2009-12
value: 0:06:24
date: 2010-06
value: 0:29:24
date: 2012-06
value: 0:10:29
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't split while iterating on the lines. What you could do is read each line, then split this line and get the result:

```
myFiles = glob.glob('./*.txt')
for fileName in myFiles:
    fileHandle = open(fileName,'r')
    print str(fileName)
    for line in fileHandle.readlines():
        print "date: " + str(line.split(' ')[0])
        print "value: " + str(line.split(' ')[1])
```